# Too High Ohm Load

Tags: resistors

I have a single 3.0 ohm sub-woofer and a 500W RMS amplifier.  The speaker is designed to run as a pair or 1.5 ohm however I do not have the space.  Is there any inexpensive solution?

Comment: A TARDIS maybe? Probably going to have to waste for a time traveller to arrive then steal it (free).

Comment: The Dr won't allow me to use it as I'm no longer a Time Lord.  But thank you

Comment: Yes , do nothing and consider if you don't have space, then you don't have the privacy to use 500W of subwoofer power,

Comment: 3 Ohms is high? Right. ;)

Comment: do you have a 500W sub-woofer?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a single 3.0 ohm sub-woofer a 500 watt Root Mean Square amplifier.

The 500 W RMS is marketing techno-babble. We don't use RMS for power measurements but do for voltage and current. You will be interested in average or peak power measured in watts (W).

> The speaker is designed to run as a pair or 1.5 ohm however I do not have the space. Is there any inexpensive solution?

Yes. Just connect one. Problems occur when the load resistance (more correctly "impedance" when dealing with AC loads - and audio is AC) is too low. Low impedance will result in higher current and this may stress and damage the amplifier. A higher impedance load is not a problem as less current will be drawn from the amplifier.

With only one sub-woofer the audio level will be down a little but not as much as you might expect due to the logarithmic response of your ears. In any case, you probably have independent control of the sub-woofer volume.

Mind your ears. You only get one pair for life.

Comment: RMS is used when measured at a certain temp rise and load

Comment: The problem is the speaker clips at very low volume

Comment: @ScottHilty: I suspect that there is something else wrong then.

Comment: @Tony: Can you explain further? I've never heard of that and can't imagine what the root mean square of a power measurement tells us.

Comment: FYI the question was not about volume, it was about sound quality.

Comment: That's won't detract by using higher impedance than rated speakers.

Comment: @Scott: "*FYI the question was not about volume, it was about sound quality.*" I don't think so. Re-read what you wrote and how you tagged it. There's an edit link below your question ...

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 yes actually it does, the amp is designed to operate at a 1.5 ohm impedance.

Comment: That's for  Power Rating V^2/R=P and has nothing to do with your question.  The output impedance probably in the milliohms so the load  R does not matter if more than rated. It's just a good AC voltage source